# iOS8 Unable to Stop Notification Sound after Opening the App

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, ios8

I've found the [bug](https://devforums.apple.com/message/888091#888091) since iOS7.1 about Notification Sound not stopped if user opens the app from locked screen..

My problem is even worse, I can't stop the (local/remote) notification custom sound in any way. Click the banner when phone is not locked, slide the notification on lock screen or just open the app directly will not stop the custom sound. It worked well before (~ iOS 7.0) and became very annoying when I'm trying to make my app iOS8 compatible.

I tested Google Hangout, it behaved the same way.. when the incoming call received, the sound will keep ringing - EVEN AFTER ANSWERING THE CALL!

So, is it a new bug in iOS8? Any workaround for that?

Comment: downvoting without a valid explanation is so unprofessional!

Comment: This bug has been fixed in latest iOS8 public release. no longer valid

Comment: I have a same problem.. Can anyone help us..? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ShreyanshShah what exactly is your problem? For me, the bug is auto-fixed by Apple in latest iOS8 public release.

Comment: I want custom sound in notification. I did it but problem is when i tap on that notification at that time that sound play, I want that sound when notification occur.

Comment: @ShreyanshShah are you using remote push notification? did you put the notification file name in your remote notification payload? I think this is a different problem. please create a new question with your code and link me there.